# Weird filter for function definition in Ocaml

Tags: filter, ocaml, function-definition

Sorry for this noob question but I have this function definition :

```
let f x = function
    | 0 -> 0
    | y -> 1;;
```

I understand that f is a function of x,y but why does it give :

- 0 if y = 0
- 1 if y = 1

Indeed according to the filter, should not f(0,1) give 0 since 0 -> 0 ?

Comment: `f (0, 1)` application will give us back a **partially** applied `function` in this case. Please note, `(0, 1)` is a **single** value which is a tuple of type `(int * int)` whereas the function definition that is there expects 2 arguments for a full application. Essentially, we will be invoking the above function as `f 0 1` and not `f (0, 1)` if we are looking for a reduced `value` instead of a `function expression`.

Answer (score 3):

This definition of a function is shorthand for

```
let g x y = match y with | 0 -> 0 | y -> 1;;
```

Its signature is:
`val g : 'a -> int -> int = <fun>`

and you call both f or g like this:

```ml
g "hello" 5
- : int = 1

g "hello" 0
- : int = 0
```

So, the output of the function just depends on its second argument `y`.

If you do not need the name of the second argument (right hand side after `->`) does not refer to it, you can also use wild cards:

```
let f x = function
    | 0 -> 0
    | _ -> 1
```

The different guards are being tested in order of how they were written. This is just the same in the Common Lisp construct

```lisp
(defun f (x y)
  (cond
    ((= y 0) 0)
    (t 1)))
```

Where the last term of the `cond` form is the catch-all term.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in your answer in do not understand the second condition "| y -> 1". It tells us that if y is not 0 and if y=y then return 1 ?

Comment: @Andrew In a pattern matching, `| y -> ...` is creating a new variable where the value matched will be stored. In this case, since it's not used you could have written `| _ -> 1` but if you want to use it you can write `| y -> y + 1` or `| k -> k + 1`, it's just a fresh variable

Comment: Yes, in the match form, you could as well use a wild card (`_`), because it is clear, that we talk about y. In the shorthand form, y is used because somewhere, the looked at argument has to get a name (for readability purposes).

Answer (score 3):

The notation for functions of several arguments is a bit different in OCaml and in mathematics, which could be the cause of a little confusion here.

In OCaml the function notation makes it easy to *partially* apply functions.  For instance we can write something like

```ml
# let add x y = x  + y;;
val add : int -> int -> int = <fun>
(* The addition of integers as we know it. *)
```

and specialise the first argument *x* to a 1, to define the successor operation:

```ml
# let successor = add 1;;
val successor : int -> int = <fun>
(* successor y is equivalent to add 1 x *)
```

so that we can try

```
# successor 2;;
- : int = 3
```

Note that in OCaml the function *add* we defined above is a different function than the function

```
# let add' (x, y) = x + y;;
val add' : int * int -> int = <fun>
```

See how the signature differs. In mathematics, we usually do not need to emphasise the difference and hence identify the two functions.  The *add'* function is, from OCaml perspective, a function of *one* argument, which is a pair.

In your analysis, you correctly state that *f* is a function of two arguments, *x* and *y*.  It does not actually depend on the value of x, since the identifier *x* does not appear right to the equal sign in `let f x = …`.  Instead for any value of *x*, *f x* returns the function defined by

```ml
function
| 0 -> 0
| y -> 1
```

So any of the expressions `f ()`, `f "whatever"`, `f 0`, `f 7`, `f (0, 1)` will evaluate to the function

```ml
function
| 0 -> 0
| y -> 1
```

(In these expressions *x* is bound to `()` or `"whatever"` or `0` or `7` or `(0, 1)` but that specific value does not participate to the actual computation of `f x`.)

We can try this out:

```ml
# let f x = function
    | 0 -> 0
    | y -> 1;;    
val f : 'a -> int -> int = <fun>
# f ();;
- : int -> int = <fun>
# f "whatever";;
- : int -> int = <fun>
# f 0;;
- : int -> int = <fun>
# f 7;;
- : int -> int = <fun>
# f (0, 1);;
- : int -> int = <fun>
```

If we add a second argument, this will actually return a 0 or a 1 according to that function definition:

```ml
# f () 0;;
- : int = 0
# f () 11;;
- : int = 1
# f (0,1) 0;;
- : int = 0
# f (0,1) 11;;
- : int = 1
(* etc. *)
```

We can also use parenthesis to emphasise how OCaml is actually reading these expressions

```ml
# (f ()) 0;;
- : int = 0
# (f (0,1)) 11;;
- : int = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `function` syntax defines an anonymous function taking a single argument, and pattern matches on that argument. There are any number of places in OCaml where this can be useful. Given that OCaml is a highly pragmatic programming language, its inclusion makes sense.

The *naming* of the patterns doesn't particularly matter, except that you want to be careful not to shadow other values already bound to the same name.

Consider:

```
let f x = 
  function
  | 0 -> 0
  | x = x + x
```

If we evaluate `f 4 5` we get `10` rather than `9` because `x` now is bound to the value `5` which we passed in. By using a different name in the pattern, we avoid this.

```
let f x = 
  function
  | 0 -> 0
  | y = x + y
```

Now, in this case it would have been far more straightforward to just write:

```
let f x y = 
  match y with
  | 0 -> 0
  | y = x + y
```

Or:

```
let f x y = 
  if y = 0 then 0
  else x + y
```

But let's say we wanted to pass an anonymous function to `List.map` to map a list of integers to new values, where `1`, `2`, or `3` are `0` and anything else is multiplied by two:

```
let lst = [4; 8; 1; 9; 3] in
List.map (fun x -> match x with 1 | 2 | 3 -> 0 | _ -> x * 2) lst
```

The `function` syntax cleans this up a bit:

```
let lst = [4; 8; 1; 9; 3] in
List.map (function 1 | 2 | 3 -> 0 | x -> x * 2) lst
```

Or:

```
let lst = [4; 8; 1; 9; 3] in
let f = function 1 | 2 | 3 -> 0 | x -> x * 2 in
List.map f lst
```